# Blocked resources by robot.txt in Google mobile friendly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile

i am currently testing my mobile website through the Google Mobile friendly tool available at https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

On all the pages of my website google notify me that "This page uses 2 resources which are blocked by robots.txt."

The 2 resources are:

https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/2006856415-postmessagerelay.js
https://oauth.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/js/core:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2

My website is using Google analytics and my robot.txt file has no restriction. Despite those resources are blocked Google detect my pages as Google friendly.

Does someone face the same issue ? or have an idea about how to solve it ?

Thank you.

Comment: I’d say, that tool is probably a little bit “dumb” in that regard – and might be referring to https://ssl.gstatic.com/robots.txt and https://oauth.googleusercontent.com/robots.txt which indeed “block” those resources mentioned. But since those resources are not even part of what you could probably want to be indexed as _your_ content, I don’t think this should be reason to worry.

Comment: I also received a same problem. Searching for solution...

Comment: I have no issue anymore, it stopped. I suppose Google fixed the problem because I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two possibilities:

– If these two mentioned JS scripts are not used anywhere on your website, simply remove links to them ( tags);

– If you do require these JS scripts and want to get rid of these notifications (I'm not sure if they actually affect your search ranking), download these files and host them on the same server as your website, change  links accordingly. Google will be able to index them (because your robots.txt allows that).

Comment: I don't really need them directly but google analytics do. It inserts them when the google analytics snipet is executed so i can't host on my server or remove these JS files.

Comment: It's strange that Google complains about these files – I'm using GA on all of my websites, I never received a notification like this. Moreover, these files are JS scripts and therefore not a part of normal indexing process (search engines don't run JS anyway). In sum, I would simply ignore the warnings.

Comment: Yes thank you it is what i am going to do i was just wondering if someone already faces this problem.